# jquery run interval if specific variable is met

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>    

$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
        var aantaltickets324 = $("#jappie1").val();
        var eventoptienaam = $("#eventoptienaam1").text();
        var eventid = $("#eventid").val();;


        var dataString = 'aantaltickets=' + aantaltickets324 + '&eventid1=' + eventid + '&eventoptienaam=' + eventoptienaam + '&optieorder=' + 1 + '&prijsticket=' + 0;

        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.sikta.nl/tempupdate.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#pagesdiv1").html(result);
            }
        });

        return false;

    }, 1000);

});

</script>
```

I want the interval to only run (or be active) when var aantaltickets324 > 0
I tried this, but then the var isnt set.

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){       

    var aantaltickets324 = $("#jappie1").val();

    if aantaltickets324 > 0 {

        setInterval(function() {
```

So he keeps saying that var is 0. 
The var aantaltickets324 is the value of an input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var intervalId = null; //global variable

$(document).ready(function(){  
    //adding the .change evenet listener so that whenever user puts the value in it, the associated logic gets executed
    $("#jappie1").change(function() {
      var aantaltickets324 = parseFloat($(this).val());
      if (aantaltickets324 > 0){
        startIntervalActivity();
      }
      else
        stopIntervalActivity();
    });

    function startIntervalActivity(){
        stopIntervalActivity();

        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            var aantaltickets324 = $("#jappie1").val();
            var eventoptienaam = $("#eventoptienaam1").text();
            var eventid = $("#eventid").val();;


            var dataString = 'aantaltickets='+ aantaltickets324 + '&eventid1='+ eventid + '&eventoptienaam='+ eventoptienaam + '&optieorder='+ 1 + '&prijsticket='+ 0;

            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "tempupdate.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    $("#pagesdiv1").html(result);
                }
            });

            return false;

        }, 1000);

    }

    function stopIntervalActivity(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. #jappie1 isnt picked up.
var aantaltickets324 = undefined 

the 2nd var aantaltickets324 is working, but that one is inside the function.

Comment: put `alert(aantaltickets324); ` after `var aantaltickets324 = $(this).val();` and see what you get

Comment: also use `parseFloat()` to convert string to decimal before checking it with `0`.

Comment: $("#jappie1").change(function() {
      var aantaltickets324 = $(this).val();
   alert(aantaltickets324);

Alert isnt showing after changing value. I suspect the change function isnt called?

Answer (score 0):

I've now made the interval to start when the '+' button of the input is pressed.
So now I've also got what i wanted, because when people press the '+'-button the value is always more than '0'.